# Why did my mother rabbit kill her baby? Will it happen again?

Tags: rabbits, breeding

I didn't know my rabbit was pregnant, so I threw the hair she was pulling for her babies away, not having realized she was preparing a nest. My rabbit gave birth to only one kit, I tried to make a nest and I did. Three days later I woke up to a dead bunny, its left side was open which was sad. I have no idea why she did that and I wanted to know if she gets pregnant again will the same thing happen? Will she kill her baby or babies? Or what should I do to prevent that from happening

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. We need more information about your bunny to answer the question reasonable. But we could not look into the future, only help you to make optimal circumstances for your rabbit to be a mother. How lives your rabbit? How many space? How old is she? What is her history (socialising)? How she gets pregnant? Lives the male rabbit all time with her?